# $http data vs params when making POST request

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Preface: I am using AngularJS 1.5.9.

When writing my service, this code works when posting to the server:

```
var request = {
    url: '/connect/token',
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializer(params),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
};
$http(request).then(function(response) {});
```

However, it seems counterintuitive to use `data` when $http has the usage argument `params`, with the following definition as per [AngularJS's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage):

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which
>   will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET
>   parameters.

As you can see, the documentation specifies that this argument is meant to be used only for GET requests. I confirmed as much when I attempted to use the params argument with my POST request:

```
var request = {
    url: '/connect/token',
    method: 'POST',
    params: params,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
};
$http(request).then(function(response) {});
```

When you submit the POST request in this way, you get the following response from the server:

```
{
    "error":"invalid_request",
    "error_description":"A malformed token request has been received: the mandatory 'Content-Type' header was missing from the POST request."
}
```

In other words, if I don't use the data argument and invoke the param serializer service on the params I want to pass in, my custom service won't set the `Content-Type` header on my request, I've confirmed this in the network tab of the web inspector.

**TLDR;** Why do I have to use the data argument and serialize the params instead of just using the `params` argument directly? And why is the content type I specify ignored when I do use the `params` argument?

Comment: `params` is for URL query parameters, your POST request needs to have a *body*.

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head. Thank you! Just post an answer and I'll give you credit for it. Always appreciate details if you care to provide any :)  @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

Use `params` option for `GET` requests.

With `params` option you can set URL query string parameters like `baseurl.com?myParam=something`